# How can I sort an Array in TypeScript into a new Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, object

I am having this array:

`const weatherF = [Weather, Weather, Weather Weather, Weather, Weather, ... ];` where Weather is an object with this attributes:

```
export class Weather {

  hour: number;
  temperature: number;
  day: number;

  constructor(hour: number, temperature: number, date: number) {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.temperature = temperature;
    this.date = date;
  }
}
```

It may be the case where 3 or more objects have the same day. Example:  [ (Monday, 10:00, 12 C),(Monday, 12:00, 15 C)]. I want to create a new Array that will have this form:

`const weatherF = [ SortedArray, SortedArray ];` so that every day will have one row with its temperatures and hours of it. Example:  [ (Monday, (temp, hour)), (Tuesday, (temp, hour))].SortedArray is an object with this attributes:

```
  export class SortedArray {

      day: number;
      array: TempHour[] = [];

      constructor(day: number, t: TempHour) {
        this.day = day;
        this.t = t;
      }
    }

export class TempHour {

  temperature: number;
  hour: number;

  constructor(temperature: number, hour: number) {
    this.temperature = temperature;
    this.hour = hour;
  }
}
```

How can I do the sorting function in Typescipt? Thanks.

Comment: so you want to sort the array as well as group elements by day?

Comment: It seems you're describing *grouping* not *sorting*. Well, the groups are then sorted arrays.

Comment: @AZ_ yes exactly.

Comment: @AZ_ yes, if you say so. I thought it has to do with sorting.

Comment: then its a duplicate, you can [group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects) and then sort.

Comment: @AZ_ can you please adjust it to my problem since I am new and I tried the post you sent but does not work.

Comment: you can edit your question with what you have tried.